# Do concept of linear independence exist in geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

> Just like in linear algebra we encounter concept of linear independence spanning set. **Does there exist any such concept in geometry**? (For example can a circle and straight line span a $\mathbb R^2$ space?)

Comment: If you want to think about the span of two vectors as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$, then perhaps you want the “span” of a circle and a line to be a cylinder $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$. However, geometry is a bit more complicated because a Mobius strip is also a circle with lines attached, so this starts to feel like a discussion of [fiber bundles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle)...

Comment: @SantanaAfton I have a very little knowledge in geometry, the question just came to my mind, I would like to know **under which branch or chapters of mathematics do these kind of questions occurs**? Actually I have not understood your comment completely well, like what is $S^1$ ?